# Error while adding Foreign Key from MVC Models

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Here are my Models

```
  [Table("Stationery")]
public class Stationery
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

[Table("Orders")]
public class Order
{
    [Key]
    public int CustomerID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Stationery")]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

On adding controller to Order I am getting following error...

saying that :

> Unable to retrieve Metadata for Models.Order. The foreign key attribute on property 'ID' on type 'Models.Order' is invalid. The navigation property 'Stationery' was not found on the dependent type 'Models.Order'. The name value should be a valid navigation property name.

Please Help!!

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create your model like this to add relationship, your both do not know about the relation, this will work if its one to one relation:

```
[Table("Stationery")]
public class Stationery
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Order Order {get;set;}
}

[Table("Orders")]
public class Order
{
    [Key]
    public int CustomerID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Stationery")]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public virtual Stationery Stationery { get; set; }
}
```

if relationship is one to many do like this:

```
[Table("Stationery")]
public class Stationery
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Order> Orders {get;set;}
}

[Table("Orders")]
public class Order
{
    [Key]
    public int CustomerID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Stationery")]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public virtual Stationery Stationery { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I got this, but after these changes I am getting another Error saying "The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.Orders_dbo.Stationery_ID". The conflict occurred in database "MvcDemo1.Models.OrderDbContext", table "dbo.Stationery", column 'ID'.
The statement has been terminated"

Comment: your foreign key value is wrong, means if you are passing order id 0 and that id is not exisiting in order table you will get this error on inserting

Answer (score 0):

Try change code like this:

```
public class Stationery
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}

public class Order
{
    [Key]
    public int CustomerID { get; set; }
    public virtual Stationery Stationery { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}
```